# Loading large xml files into Snowflake and flattening by tag

Tags: java, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some extremely large XML files that I need to process. I used to process them using Spark, but I am moving away from SQLDW and onto Snowflake, so I can no longer use Spark. In Spark, there was a concept of flattening XML files by providing a "rowTag" to a spark function. Let us say we have this `persons.xml` file:

```
<persons>
    <person id="1">
        <firstname>James</firstname>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
        <middlename></middlename>
        <dob_year>1980</dob_year>
        <dob_month>1</dob_month>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <salary currency="Euro">10000</salary>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <street>123 ABC street</street>
                <city>NewJersy</city>
                <state>NJ</state>    
            </address>
            <address>
                <street>456 apple street</street>
                <city>newark</city>
                <state>DE</state>    
            </address>    
        </addresses>    
    </person>
    <person id="2">
        <firstname>Michael</firstname>
        <lastname></lastname>
        <middlename>Rose</middlename>
        <dob_year>1990</dob_year>
        <dob_month>6</dob_month>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <salary currency="Dollor">10000</salary>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <street>4512 main st</street>
                <city>new york</city>
                <state>NY</state>    
            </address>
            <address>
                <street>4367 orange st</street>
                <city>sandiago</city>
                <state>CA</state>    
            </address>    
        </addresses>            
    </person>
</persons>
```

If I want to flatten this XML file to look like a CSV with headers `firstname, lastname, middlename, dob_year, dob_month...` etc, I would run a function that looks like this:

```
val df = spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rowTag", "person")
      .load("persons.xml");
display(df);
```

By providing spark the `rowTag` `person` in the `.option()` function, we get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
_id addresses   dob_month   dob_year    firstname   gender  lastname    middlename  salary                          
1   {"address":[{"city":"NewJersy","state":"NJ","street":"123 ABC street"},{"city":"newark","state":"DE","street":"456 apple street"}]} 1   1980    James   M   Smith       {"_VALUE":10000,"_currency":"Euro"}
2   {"address":[{"city":"new york","state":"NY","street":"4512 main st"},{"city":"sandiago","state":"CA","street":"4367 orange st"}]}   6   1990    Michael M       Rose    {"_VALUE":10000,"_currency":"Dollor"}
```

It's a little difficult to read, so here is an image to help... [image]

Anyways, I was wondering how I could do this with Snowflake, if it is possible? I would like to avoid pre-processing my xml file if possible.

Remember, these files are *large*. 1Gb+. There is also no guarantee that the files will have the rowTag in the beginning or near the beginning - it could be several hundred lines down the file.

Comment: edit: if anyone can tell me more about COPY_INTO and MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME and if this is a valid solution, would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for you:

1. On load, use `STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT = TRUE` to eliminate the PERSONS tag, and have each PERSON object land in it's own row.  This simplifies the data and allows you to load larger files.
2. Flatten the XML to find all the paths.  For example, `select * 
   from my_table a, lateral flatten(input=>a.data, recursive=>true) b;`
3. Translate the paths from the flatten notation into the field notation and build your query:

For example (assuming PERSONS outer tag removed):

```
select 
  data:"@id"::number id,
  data:"$"[0]."$"::text first_name,
  data:"$"[1]."$"::text last_name
from my_table;
```

Where `data` is your XML column.

Hope that helps.

---

UPDATE -- Sample XML to use with query above:

```
create or replace table my_table as
select parse_xml($1) as data 
from values ('
    <person id="1">
        <firstname>James</firstname>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
        <middlename></middlename>
        <dob_year>1980</dob_year>
        <dob_month>1</dob_month>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <salary currency="Euro">10000</salary>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <street>123 ABC street</street>
                <city>NewJersy</city>
                <state>NJ</state>    
            </address>
            <address>
                <street>456 apple street</street>
                <city>newark</city>
                <state>DE</state>    
            </address>    
        </addresses>    
    </person>'),('
    <person id="2">
        <firstname>Michael</firstname>
        <lastname></lastname>
        <middlename>Rose</middlename>
        <dob_year>1990</dob_year>
        <dob_month>6</dob_month>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <salary currency="Dollor">10000</salary>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <street>4512 main st</street>
                <city>new york</city>
                <state>NY</state>    
            </address>
            <address>
                <street>4367 orange st</street>
                <city>sandiago</city>
                <state>CA</state>    
            </address>    
        </addresses>            
    </person>
');
```

Comment: Could you explain point two more? I'm not adept with Snowflake, definitely just starting out. Are these ideas sequential - meaning they are dependent on each other, or are they independent?

Comment: I follow those steps sequentially when I'm loading new XML data from scratch.  If your data is loaded, and you've figured out Snowflake's XML path syntax, you can jump straight to #3.

Comment: Okay, can you explain number two a bit morre? Not sure what flattening the xml would look like, especially when its particularly convoluted

Comment: Sure.  In Snowflake, recursive flattening, like I did above, generates a row for each branch and value in the XML.  This gives you the path to the value.  I added the sample table based on your data that I used so you can try it.  I used the paths in step two to manually construct the query in step 3.

Comment: Have you looked into/heard about COPY_INTO? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html# 

Could this be what im looking for? Was looking particularly at MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME

Comment: I get `SQL compilation error: match_by_column_name option is not supported for file format XML`

Comment: Yeah, I get that too - it's quite the tearjerker. Would have been perfect.