# Load large XML files in SnowFlake

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[Target table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX9EO.png)[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn4Fz.png)
I've tried to upload a large XML file (over 700 MB) into SnowFlake and faced the error *'Error parsing XML: document is too large, max size 16777216 bytes'* when tried to check if something is loaded into stage. The same error appeared when I tried parse expected row with XML data.
Any advice from the articles below didn't help
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009IY7lKSAT/how-do-i-load-a-large-xml-doc
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008nQBGWSA4/is-it-possible-to-import-large-xml-files
[Loading large xml files into Snowflake and flattening by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398483/loading-large-xml-files-into-snowflake-and-flattening-by-tag)

Does anyone know another way to solve this problem? Or this is a strict limitation of SnowFlake?
Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test version="1.0" xmlns="http://example.com/test">
    <analytics datasource="ABC">
        <startDateTime>2019-08-01T00:00:00</startDateTime>
        <endDateTime>2020-07-31T00:00:00</endDateTime>
        <storeFact>
            <store>
                <supplier>
                    <storeCredentials code="123456789" codeS="QWE" />
                </supplier>
                <supplierScores>
                    <supplierScore>
                        <Category>Book</Category>
                        <genre>History</genre>
                        <Type>School</Type>
                        <baseNumbers>
                            <baseNumber>
                                <baseNumberID>000123</baseNumberID>
                            </baseNumber>
                        </baseNumbers>
                    </supplierScore>
                    <supplierScore>
                        <Category>Book</Category>
                        <genre>Geography</genre>
                        <Type>School</Type>
                        <baseNumbers>
                            <baseNumber>
                                <baseNumberID>000123</baseNumberID>
                            </baseNumber>
                        </baseNumbers>
                    </supplierScore>
                </supplierScores>
            </store>
        </storeFact>
    </analytics>
</test>
```

Target Table Structure:

| startDateTime | endDateTime | code | codeSystem | Category | genre | Type | baseNumberID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-08-01 | 2020-07-31 | 123456789 | QWE | Book | History | School | 00123 |
| 2019-08-01 | 2020-07-31 | 123456789 | QWE | Book | Geography | School | 00567 |

Comment: You have to split the XML into rows before you try to copy them into a Snowflake table. It will parse rows, but not if the input is larger than 16777216 bytes. You'll need an external parser to split into rows. An XSL stylesheet could do it, but that may be overkill. A string parser that splits by tag would do it.

Comment: What structure are you attempting to load the XML into? If it’s into a single column then you cannot overcome the size limitation. If you are trying to convert it into a relational structure then please update your question with a sample of the data, the structure of the target and how you want to map from one to the other

Comment: You are right - the root cause of my trouble is an XML structure that doesn't allow splitting into rows.
Please find the sample of my XML structure and target table structure in the file uploaded here:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/neglwvoauwvbong/sample.xlsx/file

Thank you!

Comment: Hi - unfortunately you are going to have to find some way of showing the source XML/target structure that doesn't require someone to download and open a file - due to the security risk. I'm sure you wouldn't open a file from someone you didn't know

Comment: @NickW, I understand. I updated the question with the image of XML structure. Sorry, I know, it's definitely not perfect. Let me know please if it's still inappropriate.

Comment: As neither the xml or table are large, please add them as editable text to your question. Thanks

Comment: @NickW, could you please review my XML structure attached? It still doesn't work correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Does the actual file have multiple "store" elements and, if so, if you split it into individual stores would that get you under the size limit? If the file has a single store then if you split it by "supplier" then would that get you under the size limit?

Comment: @NickW, actually, every element is present in multiple values. So for each of 'store' could be a bunch of 'suppliers' as well as 'supplierScores', and 'baseNumber' inside 'supplierScores'. Thus this multiplication provides a huge file's size.